# React Rout переход по ссылкам

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Всем привет!
Подскажите пожалуйста, почему по ссылкам в меню переходит и пути меняются, но отображает то же самое меню?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ik9u4.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnqLw.png)

Код:

компонент App:

```
`import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import Nav from '../Nav/Nav'
import Page from '../../page/Page'
import './App.css'

const App = () => {



  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
     <Nav/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Nav/>}/>
        <Route path='/page/:num' element={<Page/>}/>
     </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
   )
 }

export default App`


компонент Page:

`import React from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router'

const Page = () => {

  const params = useParams()
  console.log(params.num);

  return (
    <div>
      {params.id}
    </div>
  )
 }

export default Page`

компонент Nav:

 `import React from 'react'
 import data from '../../data.json'
 import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

 const Nav = () => {
   return (
    <>
       <div className='container'>
          {data.map((el, index) => (
            <Link key={index} to={`/page/${el.id}`} className='link'>

              <h2>{el.title}</h2>
              <p>Album #{el.id}</p>
              
            </Link>
        ))}
      </div>

      <Link to={'/'}>Home</Link>
   </>
  )
 }

 export default Nav`
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код текстом, для этого отредактируйте вопрос, воспользовавшись кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1517896/edit)

Comment: ---Сделано---

Comment: Странно, в [песочнице все работает](https://codesandbox.io/s/router-ggw6w5?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Да, спасибо. Работает оказывается. Я просто поставил компонент <Nav/> статичным и не замечал что содержимое ссылок отрисовывается внизу